# Privatemsg Module and custom timestamp

Tags: 7, privatemsg

By default the [Privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) Module has three timestamp displays for various lengths the message has been sent. After a certain point the listed 'time' changes.

What I want to do is append the next timestamp to the end of the current one. This way it remains the details of minutes and date posted as time moves forward.

**Example: after 24hrs, instead of it just saying 'Oct 8' I want it to say 'oct 8 12:45' and after a year '2014 oct 8 12:45'**

I think I found the code in the module where timestamps are printing, I just can't figure out how to add to it.

```
function privatemsg_date_formats() {
  $formats = array('g:i a', 'H:i', 'M j', 'j M', 'm/d/y', 'd/m/y', 'j/n/y', 'n/j/y');
  $types = array_keys(privatemsg_date_format_types());
  $date_formats = array();
  foreach ($types as $type) {
    foreach ($formats as $format) {
      $date_formats[] = array(
        'type' => $type,
        'format' => $format,
        'locales' => array(),
      );
    }
  }
  return $date_formats;
}


function privatemsg_date_format_types() {
  return array(
    'privatemsg_current_day' => t('Privatemsg: Current day'),
    'privatemsg_current_year' => t('Privatemsg: Current year'),
    'privatemsg_years' => t('Privatemsg: Other years'),
  );
}


function privatemsg_format_date($timestamp) {
  if ($timestamp > ((int)(REQUEST_TIME / 3600)) * 3600) {
    return t('@interval ago', array('@interval' => format_interval(abs(REQUEST_TIME - $timestamp), 1)));
  }
  if ($timestamp > ((int)(REQUEST_TIME / 86400)) * 86400) {
    return format_date($timestamp, 'privatemsg_current_day');
  }
  if ($timestamp > mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, date('Y'))) {
    return format_date($timestamp, 'privatemsg_current_year');
  }
  return format_date($timestamp, 'privatemsg_years');
}
```

Comment: Put some more info. Its unclear what are you asking

Comment: I want to be able to have a 'long' date option for my private messages. Example: after 24hrs, instead of just saying 'Oct 8' i want it to say 'oct 8 12:45'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these two date formats (in `admin/config/regional/date-time/formats`):

```
M d H:i

Y M d H:i
```

After that choose above created date formats (in `admin/config/regional/date-time`)
in

**Privatemsg: Current year** & **Privatemsg: Other years**  respectively.

Comment: That Did The trick! Simple But Elegant.

Answer (score -1):

Day     ---     ---
d   Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros   01 to 31
D   A textual representation of a day, three letters    Mon through Sun
j   Day of the month without leading zeros  1 to 31
l (lowercase 'L')   A full textual representation of the day of the week    Sunday through Saturday
N   ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0)     1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)
S   English ordinal suffix for the day of the month, 2 characters   st, nd, rd or th. Works well with j
w   Numeric representation of the day of the week   0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)
z   The day of the year (starting from 0)   0 through 365
Week    ---     ---
W   ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday (added in PHP 4.1.0)     Example: 42 (the 42nd week in the year)
Month   ---     ---
F   A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March  January through December
m   Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros   01 through 12
M   A short textual representation of a month, three letters    Jan through Dec
n   Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros    1 through 12
t   Number of days in the given month   28 through 31
Year    ---     ---
L   Whether it's a leap year    1 if it is a leap year, 0 otherwise.
o   ISO-8601 week-numbering year. This has the same value as Y, except that if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)    Examples: 1999 or 2003
Y   A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits   Examples: 1999 or 2003
y   A two digit representation of a year    Examples: 99 or 03
Time    ---     ---
a   Lowercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem   am or pm
A   Uppercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem   AM or PM
B   Swatch Internet time    000 through 999
g   12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros     1 through 12
G   24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros     0 through 23
h   12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    01 through 12
H   24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23
i   Minutes with leading zeros  00 to 59
s   Seconds, with leading zeros     00 through 59
u   Microseconds (added in PHP 5.2.2). Note that date() will always generate 000000 since it takes an integer parameter, whereas DateTime::format() does support microseconds if DateTime was created with microseconds.    Example: 654321
Timezone    ---     ---
e   Timezone identifier (added in PHP 5.1.0)    Examples: UTC, GMT, Atlantic/Azores
I (capital i)   Whether or not the date is in daylight saving time  1 if Daylight Saving Time, 0 otherwise.
O   Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours     Example: +0200
P   Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) with colon between hours and minutes (added in PHP 5.1.3)    Example: +02:00
T   Timezone abbreviation   Examples: EST, MDT ...
Z   Timezone offset in seconds. The offset for timezones west of UTC is always negative, and for those east of UTC is always positive.  -43200 through 50400
Full Date/Time  ---     ---
c   ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5)  2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00
r   » RFC 2822 formatted date   Example: Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200
U   Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)

and you can used :
$date = date("character");

Comment: Did you just copy/paste the php.net/date docs here?